# How to fetch text value from a popup window when it appears?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to fetch a text value from a popup window. This popup window appears when we scroll page vertically down. Here is the code snippet

```
<div class="talk-button animated slideInUp in">
    <a type="button">
    <span class="hidden">Would you like to talk to us about this article?</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and my JavaScript

```
var listen = "Would you like to talk to us about this article?"; 
var bodytext = $(".hidden").text(); 

if (listen == bodytext) { 
   console.log("bodytext", bodytext); 
   alert("Value is " + bodytext); 
}
```

Comment: Please also post your JS that you are using that isn't working.

Comment: Thanks a lot in advance. My last question is this that I only want to fetch this text when popup window appears. Thanks

Comment: I'm using this JS code.                                                                 
 var listen = "Would you like to talk to us about this article?";
  var bodytext = $(".hidden").text();
  if (listen == bodytext){
  console.log("bodytext",bodytext);
  alert("Value is "+bodytext);
  }

Comment: Does the popup element exist when the page is first loaded? Your code works if the element is there: http://jsfiddle.net/qjxu8oym/

Comment: @justDan Yes, element exist when the page is first loaded. But want to fetch only when pop appears when I scroll the page from top to down. Thanks

Comment: @Amit So there's an event that fires on scroll and shows the popup, right? If so then I'd put that `if` statement inside the function that displays the popup. It's hard to say though without also seeing the code that displays the popup.